# POST data via VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

this is the visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="Search">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <label>Tag</label>
             <input type="text" name='tag'/><br/>
            <label>Location</label>
             <input type="text" name='location' /><br/>         
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!find}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the controller class

```
public with sharing class Search 
{ 
    public PageReference find() {        
        return null;
    }
}
```

So i want to send tag and location into the find method and print them on visualforce page .I've no idea how can i do this.Can anybody help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<apex:page controller="Search">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <label>Tag</label>
             <apex:inputText value="{!strTag}"/><br/>
            <label>Location</label>
               <apex:inputText value="{!strlocation}"/><br/>     
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!find}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public with sharing class Search 
{ 
    public String strTag {get;set;}
    public String strlocation {get;set;}
    public PageReference find() { 

        system.debug('========strTag======='+strTag);
        system.debug('========strlocation======='+strlocation);      
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked !. if i want those outputs on the page back.how i do it

Comment: what do you mean on page back ?

Comment: On the same page where the form is

Comment: `<apex:form >` Salesforce use there standard component and generate html form tag on page

Comment: Actually the thing is that on your example you just print them on log but if i want them to display on VisualForce page then how to do that

Comment: use `<apex:outputText value="{!strlocation}">`

Comment: @moinkhan any issue. Can you pls let me know what do you mean `print them on visualforce page` DO you want to create pdf?

Answer (score 2):

You should:

- Define variables for each input in the controller OR
- If using an object (inputs are the field of the object) - define a new instance of the object in your controller
- Use visualforce tags `apex:inputText` of `apex:inputField`
- Use a `apex:commandButton` to be able to submit your inputs and send it back to the controller

Very helpful for you will be:

- [Visualforce Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/)
- [Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/)

Good luck!